# JDialog renderng issue with blocked operation

Tags: java, jdialog

An application should display a modal information dialog (JDialog class) after the user has entered their login credentials. This is needed because, in the case of first login or reset profile, the application needs to set up a few things, while this is done, the user should not be able to click anything and see the dialog.

My first approach was the following:

```
 if(hasLoggedIn){
        myInfoDialog.displayLogin();
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
        } catch (Exception e){}
    }
```

The class "myInfoDialog" will call an info dialog:

```
  public void displayLogin(){
        myJDialog.setLogin()
  }
```

And the setLogin Metod of the JDialog will do:

```
  public void setLogin(){
    okButton.setVisible(false);
    okButton.setEnabled(false);
    cancelButton.setVisible(false);
    cancelButton.setEnabled(false);
    iconLabel.setIcon(infoIcon);
    dialogTextField.setText(initMsg);
    this.setVisible(true);
 }
```

The issue is, that  `myInfoDialog.displayLogin();` will only show the dialog frame and title, and an empty white body looks like the rendering was incomplete. After the 5s of sleep, which I used to simulate the background operation after login, the dialog will finish rendering. But in the final case, this would be the moment where the dialog would be set to invisible.

As a first try to solve the problem, I've implemented a swing worker:

```
SwingWorker<Void, Void> mySwingWorker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {

                    //Here you put your long-running process...

                    myInfoDialog.displayLogin();
                    return null;
                }
            };
```

And used like this:

```
 if(hasLoggedIn){
    mySwingWorker.execute();
    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
    } catch (Exception e){}
}
```

But the issue still persists.
What method could be used to display and render the dialog, regardless of other code execution?

Comment: Can you include the code for your dialog?

Comment: Which part you want to see?

Comment: This could be complicated and other part of your code can affect on the issue. It is recommended for you to build "minimum" reproducing example, and present the whole project here, if you want to resolve quick.

Comment: Use a SeingWorker to execute the long running/blocking operation

Comment: Do not sleep in the Swing event dispatch thread. If you do not want users to be able to interact with your UI, either disable your components (yes, that is a lot of work) or "block" your UI in a different way (e.g. showing a indeterminate progress bar in a modal dialog)  while your background task is running.

Comment: Sleep is implemented to simulate the blocking task for simplification of the process

Comment: @snx The point is that you may not block the Swing event dispatch thread (EDT) at all. This is why your dialog does not paint itself completely. A SwingWorker moves the long running task in a background thread and prevents blocking the EDT. As a result, users are still able to interact with the UI (which is usually what you want). If you want to prevent interaction, see my previous comment. In any case, do not sleep - not even to simulate blocking, because this problem is about preventing user interaction *without* blocking.

Comment: @snx Or rather, if you want to use sleeping to simulate the long running task, you need to sleep in the SwingWorker's background thread.

Comment: Read the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) and the SwingWorker.